# How do I Copy Files into my Working Tree from Another Commit us git difftool?

Tags: git, diff

I have tried using Meld and Beyond Compare and they both have the same behavior. I run the following command on a feature branch:

```
git difftool --dir master &
```

The command brings up my difftool, which could be Meld or Beyond Compare.

I then copy files from master, that do not exist in the feature branch, to my feature branch. After I close the difftool, those files are not added into my working tree.

Is it possible to perform this operation? Sometimes I move or delete files, but want to undo those moves, or deletes. I am hoping to undo them with a visual difftool. Perhaps I am using the wrong git command.

Comment: It sounds like you might have an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) on your hands. Moving content from one branch to another should almost always be accomplished (in decreasing probability of complications) by merging or rebasing branches, cherry-picking or reverting commits or checkout of individual files.

Answer (score 1):

The command to copy a file from a different commit/branch into the working tree (and to prepare to put it into the next commit) is:

```
git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...
```

As [its documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203) explains:

> Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents in the index or in the `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit). When a `<tree-ish>` is given, the paths that match the `<pathspec>` are updated both in the index and in the working tree.

`git difftool` doesn't help here.

Read more about [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to fall back on git checkout, but I think it makes sense now that I thank about it. The difftool can apply changes to files in the working tree, but it doesn't have knowledge, or care, about what VCS it is being called from. Since that's the case, the tool doesn't know how to bring the file back via git. Alright, thanks for clearing that up. Maybe there's another visual tool out there with deeper integration with git that can do this.

Comment: @Jake88 Alternately, you can revert changes if they are committed in a nice atomic way. Git thinks in snapshots, and treats files more like metadata than anything else (which is why you can track history across file moves, and even track code that has been moved between files). It makes life working in git a lot easier if you try to think of changes in terms of commits rather than files as well.

Comment: The difftool is invoked by Git with files from the working tree or with temporary files that contain the version of a file as it was on a different commit. The diff tool itself doesn't know and doesn't are about Git branches or history. Git is the one that parses the command line, checks out the files from the appropriate commits in temporary files (if they are not files in the working tree) and invokes the diff tool.